# Enabling Instagram Chat API

Tags: instagram, private-messaging

I want to enable users of my app to message other Instagram users and also the app to send notifications to Instagram users.

Where can I find the API calls used my Instagram apps like InstaDM and Instachat which enables users to message/chat other Instagram users?

The API Console doesn't show any messaging/posting functions (unlike Twitter & Facebook)
http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram doesn't support chat on its API :(